# react-app-rewired start works but not build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

I have been having an issue with my website where I run "**yarn start**" and the site runs just fine. When I use the command "**yarn build**" all my images are placed inside the build folder but it does not add the index or any of the static stuff.

These are my scripts.

```
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test",
```

When I change the build script to `"build": "react-scripts build"` I get the error

```
Cannot find module: 'components/header'. Make sure this package is 
installed.

You can install this package by running: yarn add components/header.
```

My site uses babel to map these imports

config-overrides.js

```
const { useBabelRc, override, addWebpackModuleRule } = require('customize-cra');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

module.exports = override(
  useBabelRc(),
  addWebpackModuleRule({
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'babel-loader' },
      {
        loader: '@linaria/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: 'src/.linaria_cache',
          sourceMap: isDev,
        },
      },
    ],
  }),
  addWebpackModuleRule({
    test: /-icon\.svg$/,
    use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
  })
);
```

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['react-app', { flow: false, typescript: true }], '@linaria'],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
          components: './src/components',
          styles: './src/styles',
          assets: './src/assets',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

When I use yarn build as normal it just loads normal and then says done. is their any reason why this works with yarn start and not build?

Comment: Same issue here